# Is there an easier way to compare iOS to Android apps than manually checking each app?

Tags: iphone, ios, android

Next year, I'm getting myself a new phone, and it'll either be a Nexus or an iPhone. I'm currently using a Samsung Galaxy S4, but I'm fed up with how slow security updates occur and how often Samsung installs random crapware on my phone that I didn't ask for. In addition, the S4 is at the end of its lifecycle and might not get a full version of Android 6.0.

I'm currently verifying whether switching to iOS won't lock me out of any of my apps. I have spent barely any money on in-game app purchases for Android, so that's not holding me back. However, I have a number of apps that I use weekly, often even daily, and I want to make sure I still have access to those, or at least something similar.

I could manually check each app on the itunes store, but that's a long and manual process that I would prefer to keep as a last resort. Is there an easier way to check what Android apps are available on iOS or at least have something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borrow an old iPhone and [run the Apple migration tool](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201196) by following the setup directions on iOS 9 or you could use the [Relo tool](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=relo%20app&ia=apps) to attempt a dry-run on the Android side.

That way, you can actually use the new OS for a bit and if it's unlocked, you could swap SIM cards between the two devices. If you don't mind the cash outlay, you could also buy a new phone outright and educate yourself on the return policy if you're mostly sure the change will be for good.

Comment: I was actually looking for a solution that doesn't require me to have an iOS device handy. I don't have an old iPhone that I can use. I would prefer a solution that just does the scan, and I'm not sure whether Relo allows that, judging from the app description on the play store.

Comment: I've checked, Relo does not allow a dry run, it seems. It starts directly on the QR code to scan.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Oh well - at least you know there are options if you take the plunge. Good luck - perhaps another android user has worked on a nice tool to do what you wish.